# Converting Plain Text to Clickable link or Link to PlainText in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, html

I need your advice with converting plain text to an URL.

The scenario will be this: The user will select some entry and then click a "convert to link" button.

The entry text the user selected will convert to `(link: selected_text)`. I do it with JavaScript. And after that, when he clicks the Save button to save all his entry, I don't know how to store `(link: selected_text)` in tha database.

The URL will be like this: `www.mysite.aspx?t=selected_text`.

I can convert `(link: selected_text)` by using replace function in code-behind. But then I don't know how to show user as clickable and also by not showing `<a href="www.mysite.aspx?t=selected_text">`

It can be difficult to understand therefore I will show some of my codes to explain.

```
Private Sub Save(ByVal Entry As String) ' Entry Comes from entry textbox '

  Dim elected As String
  selected = Entry.Replace("(link: ", "<a href http://www.mysite.com?link=")
  selected = Entry.Replace(")", ">")

  ' then here starts save but not necessary to show '

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

If you must save processed input for some reason

```
(link: here)
```

must be converted to

```
(link: <a href="http://www.mysite.com?t=here">here</a>)
```

Answer (score 0):

To store in database, you'll have to track the changes separately somehow and post them back to the server.  I'd suggest a HiddenInput control.

Answer (score 0):

Do not save it as www.mysite.com?t=here. Just save the entry as the user types it. While showing it to user later, convert the "(link: here)" to link and show that.

Answer (score 0):

Save the post as the user wrote it. This will make it easier to allow editing of the post later. When you render the message you should use a regular expression to replace it with a real link. You should never replace all ")" with ">". What happends if i write "hello (world)"?

The result:
Hello (world>

You can find great regular expressions here:
http://regexlib.com